# Python Grid Generator

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a code that solve a Dirichlet boundary value problem (Poisson's Equation). The main issue that I have is that I do not have any idea how to write a "grid generator" to generate my domain from which to extract my matrices. The python programming course I took never touched on anything like this. I will leave my domain and the discretization of the differential operator below. Any help to get me started would be much appreciated. Hope this explanation was clear!

[image]

If it is too small to see, the `y` axis goes from `0-4` and the `x` from `0-5`.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: So you want a 2D list with dimensions 5 by 6? is `grid = [[None for y in range(5)] for x in range(6)]` sufficient?

Comment: I don't have any code to show. As I have mentioned, I have never done anything with python even similar to this.

Comment: @Kevin I also need to be able to change the stepsize of the grid. I.e.  When h=1,1/2... etc. how would I work that into that line? Edit: To make this a bit more clear. How would I change the increment between points in the grid (making smaller boxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grid can be thought of as a list wherein each element in the list is itself a list. This nets you a two-dimensional matrix-like object:

```
myList = [[None for i in range(10)] for k in range(10)]
```

will, for instance, make you a 10x10 grid. You can change the expression to create grids of varying sizes and content (ie, instead of `None` substitute your computation, and instead of the `range(10)` expressions you substitute whatever it is that conditions the length of the row/col).